# error while sending message from extension script to content script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

extension script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id,{"askDomain":true},function(response) {
            if(response.domain) {
                console.log(response.domain);
                populateExtension(response.domain);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

content script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(["askDomain"],function(request,sender,sendResponse) {
        console.log("asking domain");
        if(request.askDomain) {
            // sendResponse({"domain":window.location.href});
        }
    });
```

I am sending message from extension scrip to content script. When the page loads I receive this error on the content page console:

extensions::event_bindings:266Uncaught Error: This event does not support filters.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You're using an invalid syntax for [chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage).

Comment: awesome! thank you so much. @wOxxOm